# How to create TCP client and manage many TCP connections (probably with SocketAsyncEventArgs and Reactive Extensions)?

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, tcp, reactive-programming

I'm developing a WPF application, that could repeatedly connect to multiply servers via **TCP protocol** and manage TCP connections (about **200 connections**, maybe more) efficiently. There is a list of IP addresses in application, I should connect to each of address, send command string (json object) and get response as json object.

I should avoid performance bottlenecks and enhance the overall responsiveness of my application by using asynchronous programming. There is a **SocketAsyncEventArgs** class that provide an alternative asynchronous pattern that can be used by specialized high-performance socket applications. This class was specifically designed for network server applications that require high performance.

Ok, I guess **SocketAsyncEventArgs** is what I'm looking for. To handle request response I should create event handler and attash to Completed event.  So I'm getting an asynchronous and event-based code and this is difficult topic for me. I have searched for libraries that can help me with this situation and I found a **Reactive Extensions (Rx)**.

> The Reactive Extensions (Rx) is a library for composing asynchronous
>   and event-based programs using observable sequences and LINQ-style
>   query operators.  Using Rx, developers represent asynchronous data
>   streams with Observables, query asynchronous data streams using LINQ
>   operators, and parameterize the concurrency  in the asynchronous data
>   streams using Schedulers. Simply put, Rx = Observables + LINQ +
>   Schedulers.

There is a example of Reactive Extensions for WebClient:

```
var client = new WebClient();
var downloadedStrings = Observable.FromEventPattern(client,
"DownloadStringCompleted");
downloadedStrings.Subscribe(
data =>
{
    var eventArgs = (DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs)data.EventArgs;
    if (eventArgs.Error != null)
    Trace.WriteLine("OnNext: (Error) " + eventArgs.Error);
    else
    Trace.WriteLine("OnNext: " + eventArgs.Result);
},
ex => Trace.WriteLine("OnError: " + ex.ToString()),
() => Trace.WriteLine("OnCompleted"));

client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://invalid.example.com/"));
```

Is it possible to put here SocketAsyncEventArgs instance and use it with Reactive Extensions? Or this is a bad idea?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use **SocketAsyncEventArgs** with WebClient class. There are many classes for TCP communications in .Net framework. **SocketAsyncEventArgs** works ONLY with [Socket class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.sockets.socket(v=vs.110).aspx). But this class is hard to use, try more simple and user-friendly classes like [TcpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) or WebClient. Maybe performance of these classes are enough for your application. All communications classes can be used with asynchronous programming model through events or asynchronous methods.